# Run .pkg files in Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, fedora

Is it possible to run `.pkg` files in Ubuntu or Fedora. If so, how do I start with it?

What's [.pkg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.pkg) file? It's a file format used in Mac systems(Apple Inc.)

Is there any alternatives which can run `.pkg` files in Linux distros? ( specifically Ubuntu or Fedora, I'm using latest version in both distros).

Comment: What is a `.pkg` file? What would it mean to _run one_?

Comment: Sorry for that, .pkg is a format used in Mac systems. Here's the wiki link for that - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.pkg. I'll edit the description.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can unpack the Xar format using the [`xar` archiver](http://code.google.com/p/xar/); perhaps the [`ark`](http://www.kde.org/) archive front-end can also handle the Xar format, as it links against `libarchive12`, which provides read-only support for the Xar format.

[OS X uses the Mach-O executable format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mach-O), while Linux uses [ELF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format). (Okay, Linux can also read some archaic [a.out formatted files too](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A.out), but this format is effectively dead on modern Linux systems.) [There is an experimental Mach-O loader for Linux](http://shinh.skr.jp/slide/ldmac/001.html), but it sure sounds like a *toy* at this point. (You'd also need the *libraries* that applications use in order to actually *run programs* -- that'd be another complication.)

So: Yes, you can unpack them. No, you cannot simply run OS X applications on Linux.

Comment: Yes, `ark` can open Apple `pgk` archives.

Comment: 7zip also can extract pkg files: `7z x -t* installer.pkg`

Comment: Thanks. 7zip was the best option for me to investigate a .pkg file. `ark` has dozens of dependencies that needed installing, yuck.

Comment: Since I cannot answer anymore, I'll comment here: `libarchive-tools` has a package named `bsdtar` which extracts .pkg files and doesn't require another OS of dependencies. A simple `bsdtar xvf /path/to/file.pkg` is enough.

Comment: @RenanLazarotto, yeah, `bsdtar` from `libarchive-tools` is cool stuff, thanks.